# How to call a faye disconnect event from a button press

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, faye, private-pub

My problem is related to disconnect event of Faye. I can easily subscribe to a channel from java script and i can also handle the `/meta/subscribe` and `/meta/connect`. But I want some thing like a button in my html.erb file and using that i want to disconnect or unsubscribe from the channel. I want to know how do i fire up a java script for disconnecting from the channel like we do while subscribing to a channel as given below:

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
     eval(data);
    });
});
```

please provide me a controller code or java script code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The subscribe() method returns a Subscription object, which you can cancel if you want to remove that listener from the channel.

So what you can do is to store the object in another variable named `subscription` then store the subscription object returned by the subscribe method inside it.

```
var subscription;
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
  subscription = faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  subscription.cancel();
});
```

So in this case when you click the button that has id `button` it will cancel the subscription.
I would suggest checking if you are already subscribed before cancelling.

Source for subscription/cancel: http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser/subscribing.html